# Сетевое соединение не стабильно, периодически сбрасывается ip-адрес у интерфейса

Tags: linux, сеть

Подключаю два компьютера через LAN. Одному даю ip 192.168.22.1/24, Второму 192.168.22.2/24. Когда подключаю кабель, пытается соедениться минут два, в это время нормально пингуется, подключаюсь через ssh, vnc. Через пару минут пишет "сеть потерянно". Приходится второму снова дать адрес 192.168.22.2/24. Из-за чего так происходит, и как это исправить?
Может обязательно нужно один из них сервером сделать? На компьютерах Debian и Mint.Подключится к модему полуюается без проблем. Может дело в кабеле или прямом соеденении?

Вывод команды `dmesg | grep eth0`:

```
[    0.723150] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: RTL8168e/8111e at 0xffffc90000646000, 5c:9a:d8:5b:d9:a7, XID 0c200000 IRQ 17
[    0.723152] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   23.440065] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   23.440081] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   23.440112] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   27.617718] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   27.617741] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   28.454956] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   30.120490] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   30.968197] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   34.978642] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   35.826956] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   47.515468] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   48.392905] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   49.976347] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   50.822323] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   55.099994] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   55.932463] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   57.519084] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   58.361893] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   62.451329] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   63.304467] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   64.987957] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   65.817680] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   72.348743] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   73.189703] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   80.068907] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   80.896801] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   82.488029] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   83.326215] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   84.994000] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   85.839401] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[   87.538737] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   87.594579] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[ 1415.798369] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[ 1580.078960] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down
[ 1703.792470] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
```

Comment: Была похожая проблема в дебиане. После установки минта пропала. Хотя не уверен, что такая. Просто в нём интернет отваливался - приходилось заново подключать.

Comment: А как Вы ему даете адрес? может он по dhcp получает адрес (и этот адрес может быть другой) ? это все объяснит.

Comment: @KoVadim Я даю в ручную, через команду ifconfig eth0 192.168.22.2/24. Как проверить dhcp?

Comment: после того, как соединение "отвалится", посмотрите на вывод ifconfig и его апйи. А также посмотреть в вывод dmesg и посмотреть в список процессов, не работает ли dhcp (возможно так `ps aux | grep dhcp`)

Comment: @KoVadim Строка ip отсутствует. Команда ps -e | grep dhcp ничего не выдает а вывод команды dmesg | grep eth0 добавил в вопрос.

Comment: `NetworkManager` запущен? попробуйте узнать с помощью `service network-manager status`. Или `service --status-all| grep network-manager`

Comment: еще `netstat -i` на предмет ошибок передачи, или на свитче посмотрите, только на днях было похожее, контакт окислился на патч-корде

Comment: @approximatenumber Остановка NetworkManager не помог

Comment: @EugenePetrov вроде все норм. Из разных LAN кабелей пробовал.

Comment: драйвер похоже проблемный http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=190705.0

Comment: @sercxjo смена драйвера не помог.

Comment: настройте сеть дистрибутивными методами, и после отключания/включения интерфейса адрес будет присваиваться автоматически.